# how to map array/list and datatable/list c#

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable, mapping

I have an array/list now ["a","b","c","d","e","f"], and now I have a datatable dt:

```
c1   c2  
 c   10  
 e   20
```

I want to compare dt with the array and get back something as a result like

```
a  0/null  
b  0 /null  
c  10  
d  0/null  
e  20  
f  0/null
```

I have no idea how to start with the mapping or whatever the procedure is, I tried a loop but I get `6*2 = 12` items
Could anyone give some guidelines on how to do this?
I tried to declare a boolean array,if i can find the element from A in dt, then add a true to the boolean array else add false. However i got 12 elements in boolean array instead of 6 and the position is all wrong

```
 if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < A.Length; x++)
            {
                for (int t = 0; t < dt.Rows.Count; t++)
                {
                    string type = dt.Rows[t]["Sponsorship_Type"].ToString();
                    if (A[x] == type)
                    {
                        checks.Add(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        checks.Add(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the logic of mapping the data? Anything you've tried?

Comment: Post your code so that we know what you've done.

Comment: We can give a solution if you can show that you've tried something.

Comment: @Irshad I added my code in the question. can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the output exactly as you show in you question then;

```
Dictionary<string, string> comparison = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string item in list)
{
    DataRow[] found = dt.Select(string.Format("C1 = '{0}'", item));

    if (found == null || found.Count().Equals(0))
        comparison.Add(item, "0/null");
    else
        comparison.Add(item, found[0]["C2"].ToString());
}
```

The `list` is the list with `["a","b","c","d","e","f"]` and the output is in the `comparison` dictionary.

[image: The Output]

Comment: thank you so much for the help. I have never come across with Dictionary class before, but it works like a charm in this case.